# How to trigger the '.click' event more than once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-animate, jquery-click-event

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    $('.button').click(function() {
        $('img').animate({left: "+80px"}, 2000);
    });
});
```

So, I'm a bit of a newbie to jQuery and stuff. All I want to do is make an image move to the right every time I click a button. When I run it, it works the first time, but when I click the button again, it just stays still.

I was wondering how I could trigger the .click event multiple times.

PS: If it's worth knowing, the button I mention here is actually a `<div>`. I couldn't get it to work with a `<button>`.

Comment: Please `$(document)` not `$('document')`

Comment: It does fire everytime, but your .animate might always do the same thing?

Comment: Oh! I think I realise now! My old code was moving to a certain position, rather than moving it to the right. Thanks, guys!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `+=`:

```
$('img').animate({left: "+=80px"}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 1):

try the on event:

```
var doc = $(document);
doc.ready(function() {
    doc.on('click', '.button', function() {
        var imgElem = $('img');
        var imgLeft = parseInt(imgElem.css('left'));
        var distance = 80;
        var newDistance = imgLeft + distance;
        $('img').animate({left: newDistance+'px'}, 2000);
    });
});
```

Edit: I changed the code after "remembering" how animate works

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.button').unbind('click').click(function() {
        $('img').animate({left: "+80px"}, 2000);
        return false;
    });
});
```

I must works.

Comment: purpose of this? I mean this won't fix OP's issue

Comment: @A.Wolff as author of question said, his code works only at first time. So when we return false after every click, we can do it again and again

Comment: "So when we return false after every click, we can do it again and again" Well, i don't see why?! Returning false will stop propagation and prevent default behaviour, that's all